# What python variables locate libpython[M].[m].so or pythonMm.dll?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, dll, shared-libraries

Is there a true method to find the *path* to python shared object (or dll) in python2 and python3?

```
$ for x in 2 3;do python$x -m sysconfig |grep -w LDLIBRARY; done
LDLIBRARY = "libpython2.7.so" 
LDLIBRARY = "libpython3.5m.so"

$ for x in 2 3;do python$x -m sysconfig |grep -w LIBDIR; done
LIBDIR = "/usr/local/lib"
LIBDIR = "/usr/lib"

$ ldd `which python2`
[...]
libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0
[...]

$ ls -l /usr/local/lib/libpython*
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root 15029380 Sep 14 15:50 /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       19 Sep 15 15:10 /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so -> libpython2.7.so.1.0
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root  8032648 Sep 15 15:10 /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0

$ ls -l /usr/lib/libpython*
ls: cannot access '/usr/lib/libpython*': No such file or directory
```

Comment: for **what** exactly?

Comment: On my computer, the python executable is *statically* linked against the python interpreter

Comment: @AnttiHaapala for a dlopen() in an embedded python shared object